# Define a class as a CSS property?

Tags: css, class, properties

In CSS, is there a way to use a class as a property? As in the first line below:

```
h1 { class = big }

.big { font-size: 25px; }

.small { font-size: 10px; }
```

The goal being to easily change the h1 styling by replacing "big" with "small" in the first line of code.

Comment: not pure CSS. check out SASS or LESS, they are CSS pre-processors that contain this kind of variable functionality.

Comment: http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: There are no classes in CSS. Please specify what you actually want in terms of rendering, not as invented CSS code with no meaning.

Comment: There's no point in that. The CSS stylesheet is supposed to be static. You should not use it to be "replacing" things...

Comment: I did specify what I want: to be able to easily change the class of all my h1 elements for example from "big" to "small". I understand how things are supposed to work, but I'm nonetheless looking for a solution to my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use less, sass, stylus or something similar.

With those you can easily do that.

Answer (score 0):

No is posible H1 => references an html tag